# Verify identity: $\sin(x+1)\sin(x+1) - \sin(x+2)\sin x = \sin^2(1)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following identity to verify: 
$$\sin(x+1)\sin(x+1) - \sin(x+2)\sin x = \sin^2(1).$$

I'm becoming more familiar with sum and difference formulas to some degree, but this one has stumped me.

I don't know if I'm doing it right, even, but I have this so far:
$$(\sin x \cos(1) + \cos x \sin(1))^2 - (\sin x \cos(2) + \cos x \sin(2))(\sin x) = \sin^2(1). $$

I don't want to just ask "how i do dis" and expect an answer. I am trying, but my brain doesn't quite understand all this yet.

Please help! I may be late to reply, I have work to get to here.

Thanks a million,

-Jon

Answer (score 3):

This is an identity you can use: $$\sin(a+b)\sin(a-b)= \sin^2(a)-\sin^2(b)$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll look into this as a possibility!

Comment: Just set a=x+1, b=1.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [product to sum](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html) formulas, we can rewrite the left side as
$$
\frac 12 \left[1 - \cos(2x+2)\right] - 
\frac 12 \left[\cos(2) - \cos(2x+2)\right]
$$
And from there, $\frac 12 [1 - \cos(2 \cdot 1)] = \sin^2(1)$

Comment: Thanks for your reply as well! I will study this closely to see what I can glean from it, I really want to understand this and get this in my head as a tool I can reuse.